# knex.js db call does not complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I am learning node.js and came across knex.js and bookshelf.js to interface with different databases. I am trying to run a simple knex program but somehow the program doesnt quit. Below is the program:

```
'use strict';
console.log('Getting knex');
var knex = require('./knex')({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'shankhoneer',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'knex_test'
  }
});
debugger;
console.log('got knex');
knex.schema.createTable('users', function(table) {
  console.log('creating tables');
  table.increments('id');
  table.string('user_name');
}).then (function(msg){
  console.log('Completed creation');
  console.log(msg);
  return {inserted: true};
});
```

I tried to debug and found that knex uses bluebird promises. Is my problem due to incomplete exit from a promise?
Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because the connection to the database is still open.
Add the following code after your last `.then( ... )` and it will disconnect (thus exiting the process):

```
.finally(function() {
  knex.destroy();
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Can you please tell me if finally is the way to end the promise? Thanks again.

Comment: You don't need to always end a promise with finally. It follows rules of the conventional `try {} catch() {} finally` of javascript, in the sense that the code inside `finally` will always be executed at the end of the promise chain. You should, however, always have a `catch` or else you might not catch thrown errors. Bluebird is wise enough to rethrow them if it doesn't find any `catch` in your promise chain though.

Comment: More on the matter on [Bluebird github page](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#error-handling).